# The action "Save as Adobe PDF" could not be loaded because it is not universal

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe-acrobat, osx-el-capitan, automator

I am trying to add the action "Save as Adobe PDF" to an automator workflow, but I get the error **The action "Save as Adobe PDF" could not be loaded because it is not universal. **. Automator is version 2.6 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6, and Save as Adobe PDF action is version 10.0. How could I go about troubleshooting this issue? I am new to MacOS so I am not exactly sure where/how to modify troubleshoot these actions. Please let me know if I can provide additional info.

Answer (score 0):

This fix was originally posted for Snow Leopard, after the change to 64-bit - hence the 'universal' reference, but I think it ought to still be relevant for El Capitan.

From  Adobe Help - ["Save as Adobe PDF" does not load in Automator 64-bit Workflow on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard)](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/save-pdf-load-automator-64.html)

> On Snow Leopard, Automator is a 64-bit app and the Save as Adobe PDF
> workflow is a 32-bit binary and therefore does not load. To use Save
> as Adobe PDF, launch Automator in the 32-bit mode:
>
> 1. If Automator is open, quit Automator by going to Automator > Quit Automator.
> 2. Open a new Finder window and navigate to the Applications folder.
> 3. In the Finder, select Automator.
> 4. Go to File > Get Info.
> 5. In the Automator Info window, open the General section.
> 6. Select the Open in 32-bit mode option.
>
> [image: Automator Info window]
>
> 7. Close the Automator Info window.
> 8. Restart Automator.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the Open in 32 bit mode option is not there :/

Comment: Then you're probably stuck unless you can find a newer action - I couldn't remember when 32-bit support was removed.